# signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, char

I have converted my old code:

```
#define MAX_LOG_MSG 2048
```

in the *.h file

```
typedef void (*LogMessageFunction)(char *);
```

in the *.cpp file

```
static LogMessageFunction m_MessageFunctions[LastLogCount] = {NULL};

void DebugMsg(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    if (!m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel]) return;

    char msgBuffer[MAX_LOG_MSG];
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    vsnprintf(msgBuffer, MAX_LOG_MSG, fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);
    
    m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel](msgBuffer);
}
```

into a dynamic allocated char*

```
void DebugMsg(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    if (!m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel]) return;

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    size_t size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, argList) + 1;
    va_end(argList);
    char* msgBuffer = new char[size];

    va_start(argList, fmt);
    vsnprintf(msgBuffer, size, fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel](msgBuffer);
    delete[] msgBuffer;
}
```

on windows everything works great now.

Thread 1 "ATETests" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.

as far as I can see this has something to do with the size of the buffer or the string?
Can you help?

Comment: `vsnprintf()` can also return a negative value on an error, which would also cause problems as you're not checking for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a variadic template out of it instead and use a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` for the memory allocation:

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<class... Args>
void DebugMsg(const char* fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    if (!m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel]) return;

    int size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, args...) + 1;
    if (size < 1) return; // check for error

    auto msgBuffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(size);

    size = std::snprintf(msgBuffer.get(), size, fmt, args...);
    if (size < 0) return; // probably unnecessary

    m_MessageFunctions[DebugLevel](msgBuffer.get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, I can't change the API at all. This will support the same usage as before, without any change from the users?

Comment: @Gilad I think it will work just fine if you put this in a header file (not in a `.cpp` file)

Comment: @Gilad Oh, one thing: It requires C++14. If you replace the `make_unique` line with `std::unique_ptr<char[]> msgBuffer(new char[size]);` it only requires C++11.

Comment: the problem is that m_MessageFunctions is  global static  declared in the *.cpp file
static LogMessageFunction m_MessageFunctions[LastLogCount] = { NULL };
the typedef for typedef void (*LogMessageFunction)(char *); is in the header file

Comment: @Gilad You could either make `m_MessageFunctions` non-static and instead `extern` declare it or add a function that returns a pointer to the current message function.